# Regex to get String between {} (Java)

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract a String between two {}. For example, .split(regex)

```
{Regex is difficult.}fadsfjkaslfdjsa{Humbug}asfasdfjaskdlfjlkaf
```

should return an array with `Regex is difficult.` as the first entry and `Humbug` as the second.

How would I write a regex to do this in Java?

I have tried the answers below, but I want to use myString.split(regex). I probably should have been more specific in my answer.

Should I even be using .split() for this or is there another way?

Comment: Why would you want use `split` here? It is not intuitive way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String regex = "\\{([^}]*)\\}"
```

`\\{` and `\\}` escape `{` and `}`, respectively.
`([^}]*)` captures everything after the `{` and all characters following, but not including `}`.
`\\}` at the end requires that there is a `}`

Alternatively a non-greedy capture term works, ie `(.*?)`; however, I think that the character class is easier to understand for a beginner.

**EDIT:**
To extract the contents, simply do as follows:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}").matcher(myString);

while (m.find()) 
{
     myArrayList.add(m.group(1)); 
}
```

Comment: I think, non-greedy mode is dead simple too... but it's just my opinion.

Comment: @SargeBorsch I agree, it's not complicated, but if you know nothing about regex, the character class way is probably a little easier to understand.

Comment: "\\{([^}]*)\\}" may be better to capture empty strings b/w braces.

Comment: @StefanStefanov Good call.

Comment: When I try myString.split("\\{([^}]+)\\}"), I get everything except the text I actually want...

Comment: @Skylion You didn't say that you wanted to use `.split()`.  Using the regular expression that I have will allow you to extract what's in between the `{}`, through the capturing group.

Comment: I updated the question to state that.

Comment: @Skylion This is **not** a good application for `.split()`.  I would just use this regex and manually create array entries if that is required...

Comment: What would be a good application of .split() then?

Comment: @Skylion Say you're trying to break up a `String` by using `;` or `:` as delimiters.  Then your regex would be `:|;` and that would be fine.  I updated my answer to try to help you out for how to do what you want to do.

Comment: You probably should use ArrayList here since we don't know how many matching substrings will be in user data. Then you can convert it to String array if needed.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, that would be preferable.  Edit made.

Answer (score 1):

You can't deal with nested structures with regex (this will [summon demons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1418097)), but if they are only 1-level, then you can match them with
`\{(.*?)\}`

And regex is not difficult.